# Gaussian distribution output matrix using Python

Tags: python, statistics

I'm trying to generate a random variable with a given mean of 0 and standard deviation of 1.  I'm using python and when I run the following code and graph it I get the output below. I'm not sure I understand what the matrix is representing. 
Python code:

```
px = 1/np.sqrt(2*np.pi) * np.exp(-((x-0)**2)/2)
print(px)
plot.pyplot.hist(px)
```

Output:

```
[[ 0.37859259  0.38873478]  [ 0.31480994  0.37491355]]
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Hi! Please pay some attention to code formatting, we cannot help you here.

Comment: Your code does not "generate a random variable" but rather it computes the probability density function at a given value.